# With nest.js, how can I inject a Provider that has a constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have `conversations.module.ts` that has:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ImageModule, YoutubeModule],
  controllers: [ConversationsController],
  providers: [ConversationsService, ParticipantsService, StreamsService]
})
export class ConversationsModule { }
```

and within my `conversations.controller.ts`, I have:

```
@Controller('conversations')
export class ConversationsController {
    constructor(private conversationsService: ConversationsService, private imageService: ImageService, private youtubeService: YoutubeService, private participantsService: ParticipantsService, private streamsService: StreamsService) { }
```

But what I want to do is inject the AWS S3 module:

```
const secretsmanager = new S3({ region: 'us-east-1' })
```

that requires it to be instantiated. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a custom provider. You can define an injection token (a string) and give it to an object with the key `provide` and a key `useClass`, `useValue`, or `useFactory` that determines what value is to be injected. In your case, you can do something like

```js
{
  provide: 'SECRETS_MANAGER',
  useValue: new S3({ region: 'us-east-1' }),
}
```

And now you can use the injection token with the `@Inject()` decorator in the constructor like so

```js
constructor(@Inject('SECRETS_MANAGER') private readonly manager: S3) {}
```

Or whatever the type `new S3()` returns.

Comment: Where do I do this? The `module`?

Comment: In the `@Module()`'s `providers` array. It's a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Had a similar issue but had a service with a constructor having a Mongoose Model like this
constructor(@InjectModel(Blog.name) private blogModel: Model<Blog>) { }
What value can I provide the useValue method
{
  provide: 'blogService',
  useValue: ??,
}

Comment: You should probably be using `useFactory` and setting up the `inject` array to use `getModelToken(Blog.name)` so that the factory can take in the mongoose model and pass it to the service

Comment: Ok. did do something like this but it gives "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the blogService (?). Please make sure that the argument BlogModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context." error

  providers: [AppService, {
    provide: 'blogService',
    useFactory: () => BlogService,
    inject: [getModelToken(Blog.name)]
  }],

Comment: Please create a new question or use our [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/nestjs) to avoid unnecessary debugging in the comments